# Does LCDS/BlazeDS JMSAdapter forward Selector to JMS Server?

Tags: apache-flex, jms, blazeds, tibco, lcds

I was wondering, what is the standard behavior of JMS Adapter regarding selectors,
for example and does JMS bridge forward selector to JMS Server by default

I have a client app (flex) that subscribes for topic (LCDS/BlazeDS) using selector "in(1,2,3,4,5)" that topic is bridged to TIBCO (BEB/EMS)  topic.
so i was wondering now when LCDS  receives messages, does it do the filtering or does filtering selector is forwarded to BEB/EMS from LCDS upon user subscription?

Answer (score 1):

ok,so after digging up the source code it appears that BlazeDS/LCDS does forward the selector, 
iat basically creates a connection, then session and passes down the selector ...